# Problem with Google index in my multilingual site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

Well, I have a multilingual site, in English and in German. But recently I found that, Google displays the German Page no longer. Even I search my site in German, it shows all English Page. Is there a problem with Google indexing?  And I also found a issue “redirected” in Google search console.[image: redirected URL]

[image: redirected URL]

BUT I have never met such a problem before, this is source code of my site. 
[image: source code of site]
Do you know what's the problem here and How can I fix this problem? Hope someone can give me some suggestions. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you automatically redirecting users to what you think is the right language.   Are you detecting their country IP address or using the `Accept-Language` header sent by the browser?

Comment: You just emailed me a comment: "1. If the user chooses the language "German" on the site, then the English page will be redirected to the German page when he visit our site next time again. 2. and we are detecting the user's IP Adress and his browser language to make sure the right language. So if a German user visit our English Page first time, there will be a popup window prompting him to access the German page."

Comment: If you log in with the same account with which you asked the question, you will be able to comment here.   The only reason that you are unable to comment is probably that you have two different accounts.  Perhaps two different email addresses, or one is a social media login.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Now I am able to comment here with the correct account. Could you please tell me if these two questions you mentioned before have any influence on Google index?

Comment: I suspect that your IP detection is causing Googlebot problems.   I doubt that saving the users choice in a cookie would be the culprit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Do you have any views on this “redirected” in the picture above, which by Google search console detected?

Comment: Try using the URL inspection tool on a German page. It should tell you if it's indexed, and if not, why.

Answer (score 1):

The German version of your website has a redirect to the home page. Check the result of **[Redirect Checker](http://www.redirect-checker.org/)**:

> **Result**
>
> https://reolink.com/de/
>
> **302 Moved Temporarily**
>
> https://m.reolink.com/de/
>
> 200 OK
>
> **Problems found:**
>
> You use a 302 redirect. This means, that the actually content is
> temporary not reachable and will come back soon. To use a 302
> redirection for generally moved pages is a bad idea. Search engine bot
> might not follow it or handle it as temporary. For SEO this is also a
> bad idea, because no link juice will be transferred to the linked
> page.

A Googlebot (I've set this bot's selection) also follows this redirection and does not scan your German version.

Forcing users to redirect is not a good solution. Users must have a choice.

> Google's John Mueller said on Twitter that is not always the best cast to redirect users (or bots) by the location of the IP address of that user or bot. He said it can often not only "break indexing" but also "frustrate users".

Source **[Google: Don't Redirect By IP Location](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-dont-redirect-by-ip-location-24125.html)**.